# how change the dash in \IEEEkeyword to :

Tags: ieeetran, keywords

How to change the text to "Index terms:" inside "Index term_" in IEEEtran class?

Comment: are you sure you want to change the layout of a journal class? The only reason to use a class such as ieeetran is to remove choice from the author and force IEEE style.

Comment: Yes, if you know how I can do that, please help me.

Comment: make a local copy of IEEEtrans.cls (with a different name) and change `---` to `:` in for example `\@IEEEabskeysecsize\bfseries\textit{\IEEEkeywordsname}---\relax`  (line 5288) then use that new class in your document

Comment: I am grateful for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to use the package `etoolbox` or `xpatch` to modify the code of the class IEEEtran. Below `\documentclass{IEEEtran}`, add the lines

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd\IEEEkeywords{---}{: }{}{}
```

or alternatively, the lines

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd\IEEEkeywords{---}{: }{}{}
```

(Both variants do the same in this case.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd\IEEEkeywords{---}{: }{}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{IEEEkeywords}
  Keyword1, Keyword2, Keyword3
\end{IEEEkeywords}
\end{document}
```